# How to get a specific text value when click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
{volist   name="title"  id="title"} 
    <a class="outer" href="#"><span class="inner"><b class="text">{$title.productname}</b></span></a>
{/volist}
```

Does anyone know how to get the text value of {$title.productname} when I click on? 
It has six similar tags and I just want to get the one I clicked.

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Did you try `$(this).text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need jQuery** to do this.

```js
$outer = document.getElementsByClassName('outer');

for(var i = 0; i < $outer.length; i++) {
    $outer[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.querySelector('.text').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

```html
<a class="outer" href="#">
    <span class="inner">
        <b class="text">{$title.productname}</b>
    </span>
</a>
<br/>
<a class="outer" href="#">
    <span class="inner">
        <b class="text">{$title.productnameB}</b>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. your one is very good, but since I base on the first come first serve principle, I accepted some one else's answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.outer').on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).find('.text').text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several identifiers you could use from JQuery to get to that value: Something like:

```
$('.text').html()
```

might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need, this should work:

```
$(".outer").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".text").text();
});
```

**Edit:**
If these elements are generated dynamically, use Rahul Patel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This selector will specifically target the tags containing the product names and help avoid conflicting with any other selectors in your code:

```
var boldText = $("a.outer span.inner b.text").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yopu can achieve it using `text()` method

```
$("a.outer").on('click',function(){
alert($(this).text());
})
```